# Fold not in scope

Tags: haskell

Hello can someone explain to me why this custom implementaiton of foldl is not in scope?

```
afold::(a->b->a)->a->[b]->a
afold tsf accu (x:xs)=afold tsf (tsf accu x) xs
afold _ accu []=accu
```

I've tried running it like this :

```
afold (\x y-> show y:x) [] [1,2,3,4]
```

and i get the error:

```
Variable not in scope:
      afold :: ([String] -> () -> [String]) -> [a0] -> [Integer] -> t
```

When i try to use it even simpler like this :

```
 afold (\x y-> x+y) 0 [1,2,3,4]
```

i get the error:

```
 :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> [Integer] -> t
```

Why isn't the output inferred?Why is it still `t` in the second example?

Comment: "Not in scope" means that it can't find *any* definition.  It's not a type error, it's an import error.

Comment: Well why would i need anything imported since i'm using only primitive functions.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Where is your implementation of `afold` and where are you trying to run it? The "Not in scope" error is because it cannot find `afold` at all. As Carl said, the type section of that error is not very significant (in this particular context).

Comment: `:: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> (...)` isn't an error, that's a type signature. Could you actually write the **full, unedited** error?

Comment: I solved it.I didn't place it in a module to load it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't place the method inside a `module` ,and load it.Once i enclosed the method in a module and loaded it in ghci it worked.

```
module Test where
afold::(a->b->a)->a->[b]->a
afold tsf accu (x:xs)=afold tsf (tsf accu x) xs
afold _ accu []=accu
```

In GHCI:

```
:load Test
```